# Download csv file from javascript link using python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, csv, selenium, web-scraping

I am attempting to download a csv file, which is available by clicking the button entitled 'Export Data' on [this webpage](http://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&type=fangraphsdc&team=0&lg=all&players=0&sort=24%2Cd). Given that the button runs a javascript procedure, I am trying to utilise selenium for this. My current attempt below generates the error message:

> "WebDriverException: unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'
>     (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)"

```
chrome_path = path
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
url = 'http://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&type=fangraphsdc&team=0&lg=all&players=0&sort=24%2cd'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ProjectionBoard1_cmdCSV"]').click()
```

The error occurs on the final line of code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the `URL` you have shared the `WebElement` with text as `Export Data` is within a `<a>` tag. Hence you would be able to click the link with the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Export Data").click()
```

But this solution mat still fail as your main issue is the **version compatibility** among the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using **`chromedriver=2.27.440174`**
- Release Notes of **`chromedriver=2.27.440174`** clearly mentions the following :

> **`Supports Chrome v55-57`**

- You are using **`chrome=63.0.3239.132`**
- Release Notes of **`chromedriver=2.34`** clearly mentions the following :

> **`Supports Chrome v61-63`**

- Your **`Selenium Version Info`** is unknown to us.
- Your **`java.version`** is unknown to us.

### Solution

- Upgrade `JDK` to  recent levels **`JDK Version 8 Update 151`**.
- Keep `ChromeDriver` to  **`ChromeDriver v2.34`** level.
- Keep `Chrome` to  **`Chrome v63.x`** level.
- Upgrade `Selenium` to  current levels **`Version 3.8.1`**.
- Execute your `Test`.

Comment: Following your provided solution the scraper can click on that very link @DebanjanB. However, the file gets downloaded programmatically is not the one available there in that webpage. The file the scraper downloads has an extension like `.tmp`. Manual click can let the browser download the exact file, though. Do you have any idea why this different behavior? +1 for your current solution.

Comment: Thank you - after updating selenium and chromedriver and using link_text to find the element to click, the code does download the file in chrome. I was curious whether i can open the csv directly in python (as opposed to opening the file from the download directly after download is complete).

Comment: @user3725021 Shouldn't that be a separate question :) Please Accept the Answer.

Comment: Perhaps it should. I generally try and avoid asking two questions to solve one problem, but given i didn't describe the full problem above, i've added a second question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218781/open-csv-file-from-website-directly-in-pandas-without-downloading-to-folder)